# Error in Hibernate formula: ORA-00904 - Wrong identifier

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting such exception with following model and mappings:

> Hibernate formula: Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   ORA-00904: "THIS_"."ID": Wrong identifier

There is `AccidentModel` and `CarModel`. Car has a list of accidents.

```
 <list name="accidentList" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="CAR_ID" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <list-index column="IDX"/>
            <one-to-many class="AccidentModel" />

        </list>
```

Car has many accidents, in Car XML mapping I have below formula

```
 <property name="currentAccidentId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <formula>(SELECT CURRENT_ACCIDENT_ID FROM (SELECT ACC.CURRENT_ACCIDENT_ID FROM ACCIDENTS ACC where ACC.CAR_ID = ID ORDER BY ACC.IDX DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM = 1)</formula>
        </property>
```

Id is present on both mappings and in database:

```
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="ID" scale="0" />
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">ID_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

Comment: hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final (And I cant use JPA, whole project is on XML mappings)
I thing something wrong is in formula SQL, but dont know what..

Comment: The column name and attribute are the same, id.

Comment: But I have plenty of formulas on other objects referencing ID in the same way

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your formula.. You are providing column name in place of table name....

Comment: What would be the correct version ? Info: The same formula works fine if I execute it in database and change "ID" to some number eg. 123. I dont have such subselects anywhere else but plenty of formulas are already working and basing on ID field.

Comment: Try to add alias to the SELECT in the FROM section

Comment: I dont know how.. I am creating a VIEW that will show my newest accidents for cars, and I will map this view as another enetity